# Any better way for doing a = b + a?

Tags: python, string, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and I have this statement:

```
a = 'foo'
b = 'bar'
a = b + a
```

and PyCharm highlights the last line saying that:

> Assignment can be replaced with augmented assignment

First I thought there might be something like this but ended up with error:

```
a += b # 'foobar'
a =+ b # TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

But `'foobar'` is not what I want; `'barfoo'` is.

So, what is this augmented assignment? Is there a more proper way to do this or should I ignore PyCharm's warning?

Comment: Many addition operations are commutative (`1 + 2 == 2 + 1`), but that clearly doesn't apply with strings. As Python is dynamically typed, PyCharm can't tell which this is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I believe PyCharm does a lot of work to try and determine types at editing time, through static analysis. You can certainly give it hints as to what type to expect. Perhaps if told `a` and `b` are strings, it'd not give this advice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters interestingly, it doesn't give this warning inside a function, so I can't test whether type-hinting in annotations/docstring will make a difference. I'm surprised that it doesn't pick up the assigned string literals, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just ignore PyCharm, it is being obtuse. The remark clearly doesn't apply when the operands cannot just be swapped.

The hint works for numeric operands because `a + b` produces the same result as `b + a`, but for strings addition is not commutative and PyCharm should just keep out of it.

If you really want to avoid the message, you could use string formatting:

```
a = '{}{}'.format(b, a)
```

but I'd not bother, really.